# Removing square brackets from pandas series. *multiple list elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have all the elements in pandas.series in square brackets. I need to remove the square brackets only.
Notice that we have list with 2 or more elements occasionally and it has to be preserved. *Some of the solutions online were stripping it to first index.

I am in dire need for a solution. Please..

```
ecg_id
41         [CD]
42       [NORM]
43       [NORM]
44       [NORM]
45    [CD, HYP]
46       [NORM]
47       [NORM]
48       [STTC]
49         [CD]
50     [CD, MI]
51       [NORM]
52         [CD]
53       [NORM]
54       [STTC]
55       [NORM]
```

Comment: If they are lists, `df.ecg_id.str.join(', ')` should work.

Comment: What did you try to solve the problem? Please share your code, too.

Comment: @fsimonjetz Thank you sooooo much. It worked perfectly fine as I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a vectorized version of the builtin `str.strip`, `str.rstrip` (right side strip), and `str.lstrip` (left side strip) using the `pandas.Series.str` [string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#string-methods):

- [`pd.Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) vectorized string strip
- [`pd.Series.str.rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) vectorized right side strip
- [`pd.Series.str.lstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html) vectorized left side strip

Brackets on either side of each string element can be removed with the following:

```py
s.str.lstrip('[').str.rstrip(']')
```

Comment: "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!". With your solution i guess i need to convert it to string and then get rid of the new - " ". I am not so good with pandas yet. But your solution is definitely useful and adds a lot to my knowledge. Thank you so much.

Comment: sorry - I thought this *was* a string. if your elements are lists then definitely use the other answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all the values inside your Series object are strings. So you can use the [`pandas.Series.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html) to change those from lists into raw (comma-separated) strings:

```
>>> series = pd.Series(data=[['a'], ['b','c'], ['d']])
>>> series
0       [a]
1    [b, c]
2       [d]
dtype: object
>>> series.transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
0      a
1    b,c
2      d
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works as expected. Also, series.str.join(', ') works exactly as your. Also, please feel free to point me towards more resources that would help me learn these bits.

Comment: @rightkushagra, there are plenty of data science and ML courses that explain some of the background, but no specific resource I can recommend. You'll probably pick up those approaches while you code.